# dpkg: error processing package samba-libs:amd64 (--configure)

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I have Ubuntu 16.04. I installed many packages from default repositories by `apt-get` but I have been getting this `dpkg` error since yesterday night. I am new to Linux so I don't know much.

I am getting this on `sudo apt install <package_name>`:

```
$ sudo apt install python-gnuplot 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libblas-common libblas3 libgfortran3 liblapack3 python-numpy
Suggested packages:
  gfortran python-dev python-nose python-numpy-dbg python-numpy-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libblas-common libblas3 libgfortran3 liblapack3 python-gnuplot python-numpy
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 237 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 4,192 kB/9,365 kB of archives.
After this operation, 18.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libblas-common amd64 3.6.0-2ubuntu2 [5,342 B]
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libblas3 amd64 3.6.0-2ubuntu2 [147 kB]
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libgfortran3 amd64 5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1 [260 kB]
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 liblapack3 amd64 3.6.0-2ubuntu2 [1,938 kB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python-numpy amd64 1:1.11.0-1ubuntu1 [1,763 kB]                                   
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 python-gnuplot all 1.8-6 [79.1 kB]                                            
Fetched 4,192 kB in 20s(202kB/s)                                                                                                            
Selecting previously unselected package libblas-common.
 (Reading database ... 186488 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack .../libblas-common_3.6.0-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libblas-common (3.6.0-2ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libblas3.
Preparing to unpack .../libblas3_3.6.0-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libblas3 (3.6.0-2ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgfortran3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libgfortran3_5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgfortran3:amd64 (5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblapack3.
Preparing to unpack .../liblapack3_3.6.0-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblapack3 (3.6.0-2ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-numpy.
Preparing to unpack .../python-numpy_1%3a1.11.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python-numpy (1:1.11.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python-gnuplot.
Preparing to unpack .../python-gnuplot_1.8-6_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-gnuplot (1.8-6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.7) ...
Processing 1 added doc-base file...
dpkg: error processing package samba-libs:amd64 (--configure):
 package samba-libs:amd64 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
Setting up libblas-common (3.6.0-2ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libblas3 (3.6.0-2ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3 to provide /usr/lib/libblas.so.3 (libblas.so.3) in auto mode
Setting up libgfortran3:amd64 (5.3.1-14ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up liblapack3 (3.6.0-2ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3 to provide /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3 (liblapack.so.3) in auto mode
Setting up python-numpy (1:1.11.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up python-gnuplot (1.8-6) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
samba-libs:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: have you tried sudo apt-get install -f to finish the install ?

Comment: it also give same error bro

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug and is being worked on. Add yourself to the affected users list on this page:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1581679

Comment: with all the recent security issues with SMB/CIFS protocols its worth considering carefully where you use this and ensuring you use an updated version of samba or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall samba-libs:amd64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
sudo systemctl stop nmbd

sudo systemctl disable nmbd
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall samba-libs:amd64
```

apt should be good to go from there.